# using Regions, network links, time span in kml, but GE loads up entire file on startup

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have global data for fires around the world covering three days. Projecting the entire data into one kml ends up in huge kml. I tried to break up the data in to smaller regions and also smaller time intervals.

So I have hundreds of regions covering the whole globe and data for each of these regions is divided into 6 kmls  (time span of 12 hours in each) to cover 3 days.

Th problem is that even after dividing the global data into smaller chunks, once I load the master file, GE wants to load the entire data and becomes too slow. Could there be a better way of doing this or maybe highlight what I might be doing wrong?

the overview of my kml files is as follows:

the master kml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
      <Document>
      <Region>
            <LatLonAltBox>
                <north>90</north>
                <south>-90</south>
               <east>360</east>
                <west>0</west>
            </LatLonAltBox>
            <Lod>
            <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
            <maxLodPixels>1024 </maxLodPixels>
            </Lod>
         </Region>    
        <NetworkLink>
          <name> Region NHAf</name>
          <TimeSpan>
              <begin>2011-06-01T00:30:00Z</begin>
              <end>2011-06-04T00:30:00Z</end>
          </TimeSpan>
          <Region>
              <LatLonAltBox>
                  <north>30</north>
                  <south>0</south>
                  <east>60</east>
                  <west>-30</west>
              </LatLonAltBox>
              <Lod>
                  <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
                  <maxLodPixels>1024 </maxLodPixels>
              </Lod>
          </Region>
          <Link>
              <href>NHAf_base.kml</href>
              <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
          </Link>
      </NetworkLink>
...
//more network links for other regions
</Document></kml>
```

This network links for different regions are further linked to sub-regions and the whole time span is also divided into smaller kmls :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
              <Document>
              <Region>
                    <LatLonAltBox>
                        <north>30</north>
                        <south>0</south>
                       <east>60</east>
                        <west>-30</west>
                    </LatLonAltBox>
                    <Lod>
                    <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
                    <maxLodPixels>1024 </maxLodPixels>
                    </Lod>
                 </Region>
        <Folder>
        <name>NHAf 1 0050</name>
              <NetworkLink>
                  <name> Region 1 resolution 0050</name>
                  <TimeSpan>
                      <begin>2011-06-01T00:30:00Z</begin>
                      <end>2011-06-01T12:30:59Z</end>
                  </TimeSpan>
                  <Region>
                      <LatLonAltBox>
                          <north>30</north>
                          <south>10</south>
                          <east>-10</east>
                          <west>-30</west>
                      </LatLonAltBox>
                      <Lod>
                          <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
                          <maxLodPixels>1024 </maxLodPixels>
                      </Lod>
                  </Region>
                  <Link>
                      <href>NHAf_1_hr01_frpfire_20110601_1130_0050_1.kml</href>
                      <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
                  </Link>
              </NetworkLink></Folder>


          <Folder>
            <name>NHAf 1 0050</name>
                  <NetworkLink>
                      <name> Region 1 resolution 0050</name>
                      <TimeSpan>
                          <begin>2011-06-01T13:30:00Z</begin>
                          <end>2011-06-01T23:30:59Z</end>
                      </TimeSpan>
                      <Region>
                          <LatLonAltBox>
                              <north>30</north>
                              <south>10</south>
                              <east>-10</east>
                              <west>-30</west>
                          </LatLonAltBox>
                          <Lod>
                              <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
                              <maxLodPixels>1024 </maxLodPixels>
                          </Lod>
                      </Region>
                      <Link>
                          <href>NHAf_1_hr01_frpfire_20110601_2330_0050_1.kml</href>
                          <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
                      </Link>
                  </NetworkLink></Folder>
...
//more network links till end of time step
//more network links with different sub-regions
</Documents>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple time periods split into multiple KML files then you can preselect the default time loaded at startup with the KML extension `<gx:TimeSpan>` in the root Document element of the KML file. This initializes the time slider for this time interval. For it to work, you must add a Camera or a LookAt element with a `<gx:TimeSpan>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
   xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Document>
   <LookAt>
        <gx:TimeSpan>
            <begin>2011-06-01T13:30:00Z</begin>
            <end>2011-06-01T23:30:59Z</end>
        </gx:TimeSpan>   
        <longitude>...</longitude>
        <latitude>...</latitude>
        <altitude>...</altitude>
        <heading>...</heading>
        <tilt>...</tilt>
        <range>...</range>
    </LookAt>
    ...
```

You can add the TimeSpan to your KML in Google Earth with these steps:

1. Orient the view you want to startup with
2. Right-mouse click the root KML element and select Properties
3. Click View tab
4. Click 'Snapshot current view'
5. Select/edit the start and end time you want start with
6. Click OK

Reference: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtimespan

Comment: I implemented the LookAt element and the time slider works exactly how I wanted. But when I slide the time slider while zooming over a certain region( eg Africa) the master file loads the data from other regions (eg Asia/Australia). I have defined regions and use <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>. Any suggestions on something I might be doing wrong?